# Will Covid-19 wipe out the Humanity that we know of?

Tags: coronavirus, extinction, covid

As there are multiple variants of Coronavirus and every couple of weeks later there are new, deadly and highly contagious variants of COVID-19 virus emerging from the backdrop, I am just wondering is this the end of Humanity that we know of?

Dr. Anthony Fauci yesterday warned during press conference that it will take a long time, I mean more than seven years, to return to normal state that was like pre-pandemic state.

White House officials have predicted up to 240,000 people in the U.S. will die from COVID-19 with a bulk of those deaths peaking over the next several weeks.

[White House briefing](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/04/06/coronavirus-fight-white-house-health-advisor-fauci-says-we-never-get-back-to-normal.html)

No country can be in a lockdown state for that long. I mean it can never happen. It's just impossible or implausible.

So if six billion population in this planet called earth is wiped out by then by the Coronavirus then is this it? Is this the Doom's day scenario instead of the sunny day scenario? Is this the post Jurassic Era for Homo Sapiens after which they will be extinct just like dinosaurs--T-rex, Pterodactyl, herbivorous and carnivorous dinosaurs? Our ancestors have been here around for six million years and modern day humans are here for 200,000 years. Does it say that it's time to leave the stage forever?

[How long humans have been living here?](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20old%20is%20humans&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA883CA883&oq=how%20old%20is%20humans&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l9.9166j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Here is the number of tests and cases per million in the world in curved graph. Seems slow rising exponential graph.

[Some Graphs](https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  In the US, roughly 500,000 people have died from the COVID-19 virus in the last year.  In the same period, there were about 3.7 million births.

Many people do not get the disease, either through natural immunity or lack of contact with contagious carriers.  Of the people who do get it, most recover.  The fatality rate differs by country, but it doesn't appear to be more than 10% in any country: https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/mortality  Most of those who do recover have immunity that lasts for months, at least: https://www.nih.gov/news-events/nih-research-matters/lasting-immunity-found-after-recovery-covid-19

Given this, and even in the absence of effective vaccines, it seems highly unlikely that the virus will even have a noticable effect on the rate of population increase, let alone render humans extinct.  (Even the Black Death, or the post-Columbian virgin field epidemics in the Americas didn't do that.)

As for a country being in a "lockdown" state for very long, whyever not?  It may require some people to make lifestyle changes - no more cruises, clubbing, or other activities that put a lot of people in close proximity - but it is perfectly possible to live a productive and enjoyable life without those things.  Anecdotally, while I'm no doubt an outlier, the only real change in my life is that I wear a mask when I go to the store.